# Making toggle for wearable "ONLY" to change background on Android watch face

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

Im a noob and Im having a hard time understanding the guide for making a simple configuration activity for the wearable to be able to change the background of my watch face. The documentation makes it seem simple but when I copy the code and change to my package name i dont see anything. Can anyone explain in idiot terms because the developer website is very vague.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following lines to your watch face service entry in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<!-- wearable configuration activity -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.wearableConfigurationAction"
    android:value="com.your.package.CONFIG" />
```

Then, you need to make sure that your configuration activity has the following intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.your.package.CONFIG" />
    <category android:name=
        "com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.WEARABLE_CONFIGURATION" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Do NOT change com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.WEARABLE_CONFIGURATION to use your own package name! Same goes with com.google.android.wearable.watchface.wearableConfigurationAction above; these values must match exactly as they are here - only use your package name where I put com.your.package.

Here are the manifest entries for the watch face service and configuration activity from one of my own projects so you can see both of these changes in action:

```
<service
    android:name=".WatchFaceService"
    android:allowEmbedded="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"
    android:taskAffinity="" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
        android:resource="@xml/watch_face" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview"
        android:resource="@drawable/watch_face_preview" />

    <!-- wearable configuration activity -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.wearableConfigurationAction"
        android:value="com.your.package.CONFIG" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />

        <category android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.WATCH_FACE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<activity
    android:name=".WearableConfigActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_wearable_config" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.your.package.CONFIG" />
        <category android:name=
            "com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.WEARABLE_CONFIGURATION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```